SSIS flat file destination, how to write line ending \\x00\\x00\\x0d\\x0a?
We have a required format of flat file, it's a text file with multiple columns of fixed length, and each record corresponds to one line in the text file. In this format, the line ends with \\x00\\x00\\x0d\\x0a, which means two NUL characters followed by line breaker. See the screenshots below for a demonstration in text and Hex editors.
With SSIS (SQL Server Integration Service), we want to retrieve data from a query, e.g.:
select
    *
  , convert(varchar(4), ''+char(0)+char(0)+char(13)+char(10)) as end_tag
from source_table
;

Then we want to route the data flow into a Flat File Destination to export to a text file. However, as a result, the end_tag did not leave anything in the result text file.
Is it possible to get our expected line ending tag in SSIS package? If yes, how to do it?
We are new to this area of SSIS, so we highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.
The following screenshots shows the expected result:

Hex Sample Screenshot
Text Sample Screenshot


Given SQL Server still has a number of C-string semantics (i.e.: NUL-terminated strings), have you tried treating this line ending as varbinary(4) instead of varchar(4)? e.g.: 0x00000d0a as end_tag

I made a mini test by querying for select convert(varbinary(1), 0x61) as col_a; and route the data to a Flat File Destination. 1) If the type is Fixed Width, we get a truncation error saying Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "col_a" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.". 2) If choose type Delimited, it writes 61 into the text file. So, in either way, we are still missing something here.
